# Ignore Swagger URL based on profiles

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to ignore the swagger URL's based on active profiles in spring boot application. I found @ApiIgnore and @Hidden, but they hide API irrespective of profile. Here, I want to hide some API's only for PROD but not other profile(i.e., DEV, UAT, etc.,). Is there a way I can achieve this. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

They are multiple way of doing this, one simple approach (but not elegant at all) is to actually create multiple Docket's for different profiles.

Example:

```html
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public Docket getDocketForDev() {
        final Set<String> produces = new HashSet<String>();
        produces.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        produces.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("Note API")
                        .description("A CRUD API to demonstrate Springfox 3 integration")
                        .version("0.0.1")
                        .license("MIT")
                        .licenseUrl("https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT")
                        .build())
                .produces(produces).consumes(produces)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Profile("prod")
    public Docket getDocketForProd() {
        final Set<String> produces = new HashSet<String>();
        produces.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        produces.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("Note API")
                        .description("A CRUD API to demonstrate Springfox 3 integration")
                        .version("0.0.1")
                        .license("MIT")
                        .licenseUrl("https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT")
                        .build())
                .produces(produces).consumes(produces)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Now after you have multiple docket's per environment you can play with this line of code:

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
```

and display endpoints based on your conditions per environment.

Comment: Also another resource: https://ittone.ma/ittone/java-swagger-3-0-0-how-to-disable-in-production-without-swaggerconfig/